# Warning: system() [function.system]: Cannot execute a blank command in line 19

Tags: mysql, exec, php

I've got a site hosted with 1and1 - who are useless! For some reason the backup scripts they provide no longer work and they can't provide me with an answer! So I thought I'd write my own, this is my code:

```
$command = "mysqldump -u [usernameXXXX] -p [passwordXXX] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]";
 system($commmand);
```

however I get the following error:

> Warning: system() [function.system]: Cannot execute a blank command in /homepages/46/
>       XXXXXX/htdocs/admin/db_backup.php on line 19

Comment: there are a lot of legs at your commmand! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`commmand` != `command`

You have 1 extra "m" there

To see if it's throwing any errors, try using

```
system($command, $output);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Cheers for that - I feel so stupid, the problem is nothing is being written to the file?

Comment: Are you putting the backup file in brackets like that?  Will that work?  It's possible that PHP doesn't have permissions to the folder you're trying to write to.  I'm not sure what permissions would be needed, but that'd be the first place I'd check.

Comment: I've removed the brackets, the file permission is 644 and the folder permission is 755 is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this:

```
providers/HtmlEditorProviders/FCK/fcklinkgallery.aspx


inurl:"warning: system(): cannot axecute a blank command in" site:.com

javascript:__dopostDack( 'ctlURL$cmdupoald','')

providers/HtmlEditorProviders/FCK/fcklinkgallery.aspx

inurl:"/portals/0" site:.com
www.ironstonedeck.com



inurl:"/portals/o" site:.com
ML Parsing Error: unexpected parser state Location: jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/content/global/netError.xhtml Line Number 311, Column 58: <div id="ed_netInterrupt">&netInterrupt.longDesc;</div> ---------------------------------------------------------^
```